# Discord Bot Embed Custom Emoji

Tags: python, discord.py, embed, emoji

I'm creating a python discord bot which will output messages in an embed format.

I have added a few custom emoji's to the discord server and would like to use these in the embed message.

I would like it to look something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdgdA.jpg except the emoji's used will be custom emojis NOT the discord default emojis.

I also want the emoji to sit the 'description' field. The custom emoji works fine in the title but won't work in 'description'.

```
 embed = discord.Embed(title="Here is the **title**! <:emoji1:52342365738338334>", color=0x24045b, description="Here is the emoji again! <:emoji1:52342365738338334>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easiest to get the [`Emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#emoji) object that represents your custom emoji, then use that to build your strings

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def respond(ctx):
    emoji = get(ctx.message.server.emojis, name="emoji1")
    embed = Embed(title=f"Here is the **title**! {emoji}", color=0x24045b, description=f"Here is the emoji again! {emoji}")
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Here's a debugging command that you can use to get information about your Emoji

```
from discord import Embed, Emoji
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def debug(ctx, emoji: Emoji):
    embed = Embed(description=f"emoji: {emoji}", title=f"emoji: {emoji}")
    embed.add_field(name="id", value=repr(emoji.id))
    embed.add_field(name="name", value=repr(emoji.name))
    await bot.say(embed=embed)

bot.run("token")
```

Call this from discord with `!debug :emojiname:`, and it should give you the information about that emoji.  If it doesn't, then you may be trying to use an emoji that doesn't exist, or that your bot can't see (generally the emoji has to be from the server the command is invoked in/the response is being posted to)

Comment: This doesn't work. Every out come just prints out  {emoji_name} with the brackets. I have tried 3 different emoji ID's in the 'name="emoji1". I tried 'emoji_name', ':emoji_name:' and '<:emoji_name:248286363862>'

Comment: Did you include the `f` at the beginning of the strings?

Comment: I removed the f because I thought it was a typo. I will add the f back in. Also what emoji name ID should I use?

Comment: `name` is the name of the emoji (what you type in discord to get it to show up).  You can also use the id instead by doing `id="1234"` with your `id`.

Comment: I tried just having the name and then just having the ID and then tried both ID and name and every result gave me the word 'None' where the emoji should have been

Comment: @MeHead I added a debugging command to the above.  You can use that to gather information about the emoji.

Comment: So I added your debug code and ran it. It works fine https://imgur.com/Ru67t00. The ID and name are the exact same values that I had inputted. When I do emoji = get(ctx.message.server.emojis, id="550929165780516884", name=":supicon:") it still gives me 'None' where I have {emoji}

Comment: The colons aren't part of the name. Try just `name='supicon'`